# SAS code. How to plot the dynamic of the variable y over x in SAS (the easiest way!)

Tags: sas

How to plot the dynamic of the variable y over x in SAS (the easiest way!), for example, temperature changes over time. Thank you very much! (PC-SAS)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  What SAS environment are you working in ? PC-SAS, EG, SAS Studio, other ?

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways are the `scatter` and `series` statements in `Proc SGPLOT`.

For example:

```
data have;
  do time = 0 to 24;
    time = time + ranuni(123) - 1.2;
    temp = 60 + 6 * sin(time / 7.6);
    rowNumber + 1;
    output;
  end;
run;

ods graphics on / width=325px;

proc sgplot data=have;
  title "Scatter";
  footnote "Created: &sysdate";
  scatter x=time y=temp;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
  title "Series";
  footnote "Created: &sysdate";
  series x=time y=temp / markers;
run;
```

[image: Example of SGPLOT scatter and series graphical output]

Comment: Here temp is function of time. But if I just have (in dataset) two columns (col1 and col2) with empirical data, can I write so:
scatter x=col1 y=col2 ?
Is one-to-one match (col1 and col2) set automatically?

Comment: Well I had to make up some data, so a function was used.  scatter plot points are one per row in the data set.  I believe Series presumes connectivity of points is by row order.  You should take the time to go over the SAS documentation.

Comment: I think the code should include row number (for col1 and col2 ligament). But I did not find it. Many thanks Richard for your help.!

Comment: See edited answer, rownumber can be easily added to the sample data.

Comment: You're very kind, Richard! Thank you very much!